# zenity dialog window with two buttons but no text entry

Tags: bash, user-interface, zenity

I would like to create a zenity dialog window with two buttons as only user input.

The following creates a window with two buttons but with a space for a text entry

```
zenity --entry --title="" --text "Choose A or B" --ok-label="B" --cancel-label="A"
```

The following creates a window with one button only

```
zenity --info --title="" --text "Choose A or B" --ok-label="B"
```

Comment: What if you put `--text ""` in first method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--question` is what you are looking for:

```
zenity --question \
--title="" \
--text "Choose A or B" \
--ok-label="B" \
--cancel-label="A"
```

You may also try:

```
zenity --question \
--text="Choose A or B" \
--switch \
--extra-button "A" \
--extra-button "B"
```

This automatically generates a dialog with just your two extra buttons. (`--switch` suppresses the default OK and Cancel buttons)

Comment: Thank you +1. Follow-up question: Do you know if one can add further buttons?

Comment: Probably not or at least I'm not aware of this being possible.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `--extra-button` as many times as you want to add further buttons.

Answer (score 7):

At least recent versions of zenity have an --extra-button flag.

Combining the value of the exit code and the content of stdout, the code can figure out what the user did.

For example:

```
while true; do
  ans=$(zenity --info --title 'Choose!' \
      --text 'Choose A or B or C' \
      --ok-label A \
      --extra-button B --extra-button C \
      --timeout 3)
  rc=$?
  echo "${rc}-${ans}"
done
```

Results would look like this:

```
# timeout
5-
# ESC key
1-
# A button
0-
# B button
1-B
# C button
1-C
```

Note that the above works similarly other dialogs, though certain combinations may be surprising.  Be sure to experiment and handle all sorts of different user interactions.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use `--info`

```
zenity --info \
--title="A or B" \
--text "Choose A or B" \
--ok-label="B" \
--cancel-label="A"
```

Comment: Using zenity 3.18.1.1 (Ubuntu 16.04) I get "--cancel-label is not supported for this dialog".